# D3js links are not being displayed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to display something dynamic with D3js, and everything is working except the links. Can someone give me a clue of what I'm doing wrong?

The code create a circular infinite caterpillar, and I'm trying to add some links that come and go dynamically. The code adds nodes and links until the array has reached 25 items. Then it deletes the first item each time it adds a new item.

```js
//window
var vv = window,
    w = vv.innerWidth,
    h = vv.innerHeight;
 
//canevas selection
var svg = d3.select("#animviz")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);
 
//link and node class creation
svg.append("g").attr("class", "links");
svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodes");
 
//containers de noeuds et liens
var nodes = [{id:0}], links = [];
var iter = 1;

//repeat an action every "interval"
var interval = 0.1;
setInterval(function() {
 addData();
 update();
}, interval*1000);


function addData() {
 var n = iter;
 iter++;
 nodes.push({id: n});

 if(n > 25 ){
  links.push({source: nodes[n%25], target: nodes[n%25+1]});
 }
 if (n > 25) {
  nodes.splice(0, 1);
  links.splice(0, 1);
 }
}

var node = svg.select(".nodes").selectAll(".node"),
 link = svg.select(".links").selectAll(".link");


function update() {
 link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d});
 link.enter()
 .append("line")
 .attr("class", "link")
 .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
 .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
 link.exit().remove();
 

 node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });
 node.enter()
 .append("svg:circle")
 .attr("class", "node");
 node.attr("cx", function(d) { return 200 + 100 * Math.sin(d.id); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return 200 + 100 * Math.cos(d.id); })
    .attr("r", 4.5)
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke", "black");
    node.exit().remove(); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Animal #1</title>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="animviz"></div>
        <div id="printzone"></div>
        <script src="circular.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you! nodes and links

Comment: it looks like maybe you need to add x1,x2,y1,y2 attributes for the links?

Comment: Edited, sorry if i made a mistake, i'm trying to learn. It doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 corrections in your current code for the lines to appear.

You are splicing the links from the start and by just checking the nodes length. Considering that you start adding the links only once the nodes reach 25 you are not allowing your links array to grow. Move the splice to its own block

```
  if (links.length > 2) {
     links.splice(0, 1);
  }
```

The attribute section needs to be

```
.attr("x1", function(d) { return 200 + 100 * Math.sin(d.source.id); })
.attr("y1", function(d) { return 200 + 100 * Math.cos(d.source.id); })
.attr("x2", function(d) { return 200 + 100 * Math.sin(d.target.id); })
.attr("y2", function(d) { return 200 + 100 * Math.cos(d.target.id); });
```

because you are not setting the x or y for the nodes anywhere. You are calculating them on the fly for the node points.

After these changes are made, the lines appear / disappear (see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGyapY), but I'm not sure it looks like a caterpillar :-) (you are adding the lines as per the last *added* nodes)